# Remove consecutive uppercase words from string

Tags: r, regex

I'm having a long string where I would like to remove consecutive words with uppercase (2+ in a row) and if a punctation follows the last uppercase word, that as well.
But at the same time I would like to keep single uppercase words and uppercase words that are part of a "mixed" word (see reprex).

I struggle to implement the consecutive word group in reprex.

```r
string <- "Lorem ipsum DOLOR SIT AMET? consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero NEC velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. ETIAM-123 dui sem, fermentum vitae, SAGITTIS ID? malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam IN LOREM SIT amet leo accumsan"

#remove all consecutive UPPERCASE words including punctation (--> DOLOR SIT AMET?), but not single uppercase words (--> NEC) or "mixed" words with uppercase and digits (--> ETIAM-123)
#this doesn't work:
string %>% 
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\b[:upper:]+\\b")
#> [1] "Lorem ipsum   ? consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero  velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. -123 dui sem, fermentum vitae,  ? malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam    amet leo accumsan"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any hints are appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
string <- "Lorem ipsum DOLOR SIT AMET? consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero NEC velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. ETIAM-123 dui sem, fermentum vitae, SAGITTIS ID? malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam IN LOREM SIT amet leo accumsan"
gsub("\\s*\\b\\p{Lu}{2,}(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}{2,})+\\b[\\p{P}\\p{S}]*", "", string, perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
[1] "Lorem ipsum  consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero NEC velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. ETIAM-123 dui sem, fermentum vitae,  malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam  amet leo accumsan"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/tl26iu) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/id87T0/2).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\b` - word boundary
- `\p{Lu}{2,}` -  two or more capital letters
- `(?:\s+\p{Lu}{2,})+` - 1 or more occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 2 or more uppercase letters
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[\p{P}\p{S}]*` - any 0 or more symbols or punctuation

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, I have just updated the pattern.

Comment: What if I'd suggest a shorter looking `(?:\s*\b\p{Lu}{2,}\b){2,}[\p{P}\p{S}]*`. Would that be a valid suggestion? Is there something super obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: @JvdV I have been already pointed it out time and again. I tend to avoid such patterns, even if they are fine overall. The problem is with the optional `\s*` pattern at the start of the quantified group, it causes more backtracking in the end. The more to the right an indefinitely quantified pattern is the better in general, a rule of a thumb.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this?

```r
stringr::str_remove_all(string, "([[:upper:]]+ )+[[:upper:]]+( |[:punct:])*")
#> [1] "Lorem ipsum consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida libero NEC velit. Morbi scelerisque luctus velit. ETIAM-123 dui sem, fermentum vitae, malesuada in, quam. Proin mattis lacinia justo. Vestibulum facilisis auctor urna. Aliquam amet leo accumsan"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It would be better if the answer pointed to the *specific* package required to solve this rather than using a mega/meta package that imports literally thousands(!) of symbols.

Comment: Fair enough @KonradRudolph. This was just the OP's code with the regex improved, but I guess that's no excuse. Updated.

Comment: I honestly hadn’t even seen that the package was used in OP’s question. I still think (and you seem to agree) that the answer is better without, but now I understand why it was there.

Comment: Mmh on my reprex text it does work as intended but on my real string it also removes some single uppercase words if the next word starts with a uppercase letter.
This is my best attempt so far, which for some reason doesn't remove punctuation:
`(\\s([:upper:]+[:punct:]{1}|[:upper:]+)(?=\\b)){2,}`